# Downloading Image for Firebase into TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an app where there is a tableview that is populated by text. However, I want there to be a picture as the background for the whole table view and not the individual cells itself. I am storing the images in Firebase under the Storage Tab. Whenever I test the application, a white background only appears with nothing being loaded from Firebase.

Here is my code:

```
      let storage = Storage.storage()
      var storageRef = storage.reference()


      storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://firbaseappurl.appspot.com/Caption Background Images/Emotion/caption_back_happy.png")
      storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
           let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
           let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
           let imageView = UIImageView(image:image)
           self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set image in main queue like shown below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. Worked Perfectly